# Chat GPT api, ответ только по определенной теме

Tags: python, chatgpt, chatgpt-api

Есть какой то способ заставить chatgpt отвечать только на вопросы по определенной теме? К примеру только на юридические вопросы. Средствами python или самого api. Остальные вопросы должны блокироваться.

Инфу в документации не нашел.

Comment: Например, напрямую его об этом и попросите в первом сообщении диалога?

Comment: Нужно чтобы ответы на другие вопросы блокировались.

Comment: Смотрите документацию API. Если такого там нет - значит нет. Добавлю, что если это даже у его создателей не получилось (см. jailbreakchat), то у остальных и подавно не выйдет )

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: А вы сами сможет определить тему вопроса? "В каком году приняли закон номер 123?" Это вопрос на юридическую тему или на историческую?

Comment: Действительно, проще написать другого бота.